# Replace ViewController from existing navigation hierarchy (while handling Tabs)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift2

i can change my ViewControllers from navigation hierarchy using  `self.navigationController?.setViewControllers` by passing my desired Viewcontrollers there but i dont how to do the same on my case :

i have 3 tabs say A,B,C

and from A  i can push to A2 view controller

and from B's B1 i can also push A2 view controller (open A2 viewcontroller  via segue ) but  when i'm in this A2 View controller i want to change the View controllers in navigation hierarchy , if i go back from A2 it should took me Tab A how can i do this ??

p.s. if my question is not clear enough then let me know i'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You shoul instantiate `ViewController A` in this case and can `pop` to that specific `viewController` by using `popToViewController` method.

for example,

```
  let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as UIViewController
  self.navigationController!.popToViewController(viewController , animated: true)
```

or can manage something like,

```
   let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as [UIViewController]
  self.navigationController!.popToViewController(viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2], animated: true)   //manage index or array that can reach you a your viewcontroller A
```

You can get your tabbar's tab (i.e. viewcontrollers) somthing like,

```
  var vcA:FirstViewControllerA = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[0] as FirstViewControllerA!
```

and can pop to that `vcA`.

Reference : [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343546/how-to-pop-view-controller-to-one-of-the-previous-view-controllers-in-swift)