# How can I pop specific View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I used the `Objective-C` code below to pop a specific `ViewController`.

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[AnOldViewController class]]) { 
        //Do not forget to import AnOldViewController.h
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                              animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

How can I do that in Swift?

Comment: Exactly the same way, but in Swift syntax. What have you tried, and what goes wrong when you try it? (Specific error message or runtime behavior that you're not expecting).

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Try following code:

```
for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
    if controller.isKind(of: ViewController.self) {
        self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: what if my current view controller is a Model?

Comment: look this question:-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270459/how-to-change-class-dynamically-for-view-controller-using-interface-builder

Answer (score 45):

**Swift 5**

To pop to the latest instance of a specific class, for example `SomeViewController`:

```
navigationController?.popToViewController(ofClass: SomeViewController.self)
```

But you need to add ths `UINavigationController` extension:

```
extension UINavigationController {
  func popToViewController(ofClass: AnyClass, animated: Bool = true) {
    if let vc = viewControllers.last(where: { $0.isKind(of: ofClass) }) {
      popToViewController(vc, animated: animated)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: cleanest answer so far for swift 5

Comment: I prefer to check like this: `viewControllers.last(where: { $0 is ofClass }) { ... }`. You don't need the isKind(of:) stuff. Makes it cleaner.

Answer (score 36):

**For Swift 3+**

```
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers
for aViewController in viewControllers {
    if aViewController is YourViewController {
        self.navigationController!.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

**From Swift 4.0 and Above**

```
for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
        if controller.isKind(of: DashboardVC.self) {
            _ =  self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
            break
        }
    }
```

This is working Perfect.

Comment: Its working perfect in Swift 5 too.

Answer (score 18):

I prefer a generic way to do it.

I have this extension for the UINavigationController :

```
extension UINavigationController {

   func backToViewController(vc: Any) {
      // iterate to find the type of vc
      for element in viewControllers as Array {
         if "\(element.dynamicType).Type" == "\(vc.dynamicType)" {
            self.popToViewController(element, animated: true)
            break
         }
      }
   }

}
```

Let's say I have a FOHomeVC class (who is a UIViewController) instantiated in the navigation stack.

So I would do this in my code:

```
self.navigationController?.backToViewController(FOHomeVC.self)
```

Comment: self.navigationController?.backToViewController(vc: ViewController())

Answer (score 6):

I have added an extension to `UINavigationController` which helps you to find if that controller exist in navigation stack. If yes then it will be popped to that controller or else you pass new controller to push with `pushController` param.

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func containsViewController(ofKind kind: AnyClass) -> Bool {
        return self.viewControllers.contains(where: { $0.isKind(of: kind) })
    }

    func popPushToVC(ofKind kind: AnyClass, pushController: UIViewController) {
        if containsViewController(ofKind: kind) {
            for controller in self.viewControllers {
                if controller.isKind(of: kind) {
                    popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
                    break
                }
            }
        } else {
            pushViewController(pushController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4 / Swift 5**

```
 for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
            if controller.isKind(of: HomeViewController.self) {
                self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
                break
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

I prefer a "real generic" and more functional approach.

So I came up with following `UINavigationController` extension functions. You can also use the first function, for anything else, where you just need to access a specific VC in the navigation stack.

---

**Extensions**

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func getViewController<T: UIViewController>(of type: T.Type) -> UIViewController? {
        return self.viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is T })
    }

    func popToViewController<T: UIViewController>(of type: T.Type, animated: Bool) {
        guard let viewController = self.getViewController(of: type) else { return }
        self.popToViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(of: YourViewController.self, animated: true)
```

---

This should work at least in Swift 4 and 5.

Answer (score 4):

Find your view controller from navigation stack and pop to that view controller   if it exists

```
for vc in self.navigationController!.viewControllers {
    if let myViewCont = vc as? VCName 
    {
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(myViewCont, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**swift5**

```
let controllers : Array = self.navigationController!.viewControllers
self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controllers[1], animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5 Answer of @PabloR is Here :

```
extension UINavigationController {

   func backToViewController(vc: Any) {
      // iterate to find the type of vc
      for element in viewControllers as Array {
        if "\(type(of: element)).Type" == "\(type(of: vc))" {
            self.popToViewController(element, animated: true)
            break
         }
      }
   }

}
```

Usage :

```
self.navigationController?.backToViewController(vc: TaskListViewController.self)
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 4.0 and above Using Filter

```
guard let VC = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.filter({$0.isKind(of: YourViewController.self)}).first else {return}
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(VC, animated: true)
```

OR

```
if let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.map({$0 as? YourViewController}).first{
            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc!, animated: true)
        }
```

Comment: Alhamdulellah Working for me.....

Answer (score 2):

In latest swift

```
   @IBAction func popToConversationsVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (self.navigationController != nil) {
            for vc in  self.navigationController!.viewControllers {
                if vc is ConversationsVC {
                     self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: false)
                }
            }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this below code for Swift 3.0:

```
 let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as [UIViewController];

for aViewController:UIViewController in viewControllers {
            if aViewController.isKind(of: YourViewController.self) {
                _ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use this, because in some cases app crashes:

```
if let navVC = self.navigationController {
                    let views = navVC.viewControllers as Array
                    for controller in views {
                        if controller.isKind(of: YourVC.self) {
                            navVC.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me :)

```
extension UINavigationController {
  func backToViewController(_ viewController: AnyClass, animated: Bool) {

    guard let viewController = self.viewControllers.first(where: {$0.isKind(of: viewController)}) else { return }
    self.popToViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I adapt from all answer above. It look like **Yakup Ad** answer, because it's very short way.

- I force type by using generic for argument, that make sure you must pass only UIViewController to this func.
- I search viewController that already in stack by using .first this make me got only one VC then stop the loop.
- I also return passing VC back if you need to customize somethings.

Let's enjoy.

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func popToViewController<T: UIViewController>(_ viewController: T.Type, animated: Bool) -> T? {
        guard let viewController = self.viewControllers.first(where: {$0 is T}) else { return nil }
        self.popToViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
        
        return viewController as? T
    }
    
}
```

Usage

```
let poppedVC = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(HomeViewController.self, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func popBack(to vc: AnyClass, animated: Bool = true) {
        guard let elementFound = (viewControllers.filter { $0.isKind(of: vc) }).first else {
            fatalError("cannot pop back to \(vc) as it is not in the view hierarchy")
        }
        self.popToViewController(elementFound, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple and best solution without **force unwrapped** is

```
if let vc = navigationController.viewControllers.filter({$0 is YourViewController}).first as? YourViewController {
            self.navigationController.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }
```