# iOS Swift popToViewController by Name

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to pop to a viewcontroller which I believe is at index 0.  My ViewController name is HomeVC.

```
 self.navigationController!.popToViewController(self.navigationController!.viewControllers[0] as! UIViewController, animated: true)
```

However, the code above only pops me back to the most recent viewcontroller.  Not sure why it's not going to my HomeVC viewcontroller.  Is their a way I can use the ViewController Name to pop to it?

Comment: Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003814/how-can-i-pop-specific-view-controller-in-swift/40314079#40314079

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count; i++) {
    if(self.navigationController?.viewControllers[i].isKindOfClass(YourDesiredViewController) == true) {
           self.navigationController?.popToViewController(self.navigationController!.viewControllers[i] as! DestinationViewController, animated: true)   
           break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` to pop to the View controller at index zero.

It returns an array of view controllers that were popped, that might help you in debugging the issue.

Comment: I've used the popToRoot and it takes me back to my most recent viewcontroller.  Is their a way I can just specify the name of the viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

Add following `UINavigationController` extension

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func popToClass<T: UIViewController>(type: T.Type) -> Bool {
        for viewController in self.viewControllers {
            guard let _ = viewController as? T else { continue }
            self.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

Use as follows

```
let success = navigationController.popToClass(MyVC.self)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for viewController in (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)! {
        if(viewController is YourViewController) {
            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
            break;
        }
    }
```

I solved it like this.