# How to perform unwind segue in between several .xib files (not using storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, unwind-segue

I have created several .xib files with a navigation controller and some table view.I have a barButton. when I click that one it pushes one view onto another, now I want to come to the previous view, that one can be done by push. But my previous view is embedded in a navigation controller(here I can see the previous view but with all navigation functionality disable). So here I want to perform unwind segue like we do in storyboard. But I am not using any storyboard. I just want to know that what can I do to get the similar result as unwind segue while using only .xib files?

Answer (score 0):

use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` in the view controller from which you want to perform the unwind segue.

Comment: That will not work because my top view is root view controller and you cannot pop the last item on the stack.

Comment: Anyway thank you but i got the answer : [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djpEr0kgnUY) @askatasuna

Comment: try with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30010908/3430658