# Redirect User to Specific ViewController - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue

I'm trying to redirect users to the correct page after deletion of the place.

[image]

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

This will work, if I want to redirect to the root.

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

This will work if I want to redirect to the previous

BUT in my case, I want to redirect to a specific page that not the root or the previous one.

How would one go about and do something like this in iOS ?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003814/how-can-i-pop-specific-view-controller-in-swift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you now the position in your stack you can also use

```
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(self.navigationController!.viewControllers[1], animated: true)
```

Comment: @kyo also you don't have to filter or loop through your viewControllers ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
for vc in self.navigationController!.viewControllers {
   if let myVC = vc as? VCName {
     self.navigationController?.popToViewController(myVC, animated: true)
   }
}
```